# How to launch an sql script on a docker container launch?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: matcha
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

It allows me to run my init.sql file and build my db directly. The thing is, I constantly got this error on my docker logs :
`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 75: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql: Permission denied`

I've checked inside my container. The file is at the right location and has these permissions : `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  183 Dec  5 13:57 init.sql`

I also tried to build mysql service via a Dockerfile instead of directly indicating a volume in my docker-compose :

```
FROM mysql:8.0


# Generate the init.sql script
RUN echo "CREATE DATABASE matcha;" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
RUN echo "CREATE TABLE matcha.user (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));" >> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

# Make the init.sql script readable by the mysql user
RUN chown mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

To try to give the permissions, inside the container. Still fails. Any idea why ?

EDIT: I'm not root on host and `mysql` isn't install or can be install on host. Can't either `adduser` to provide the `chown` to `mysql` user on host.

Comment: Given what you've shown, I might expect `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` inside the container to be a _directory_, and there to be a corresponding empty `init.sql` directory on the host.  That would be consistent with that error too.  Does that match what you're seeing?

Comment: (For what you're showing specifically, also consider a path of using the unmodified `mysql` image, using its environment-variable configuration to create the initial database, and then using your application framework's database migration system to create tables.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, i've checked in my container. the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` is a file in my container and also on host.